# Python with envoy, how to use variables

Tags: python, bash, shell, python-2.7

I try to use Python [envoy](https://github.com/kennethreitz/envoy) for better access to Shell programs. But i have a problem that i want to delete all items of a folder, but envoy can't handle my varaible:

```
import envoy
import os

# Check for a empty folder. 
if len(os.listdir(csv_save_path)) != 0:
    for item in os.listdir(csv_save_path):
        result = envoy.run('rm -v',item)
        print result.std_out
        print result.std_err
```

Output:

```
"rm: missing operand\nTry `rm --help' for more information.\n"
```

I don't want use subprocces. Anyone a idea what is wrong?

Edit:

Thank for your quick response. Now i get this error message:

```
    Exception in thread Thread-4:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/threading.py", line 552, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/threading.py", line 505, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/envoy/core.py", line 40, in target
    bufsize=0,
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1228, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

*** AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'returncode'
```

But i check on the path of the  file, with and without path, it's failing.

Edit: The Solution is to use %s to get the item to the right place.

```
import envoy
import os

# Check for a empty folder. 
if len(os.listdir(csv_save_path)) != 0:
    for item in os.listdir(csv_save_path):
        result = envoy.run('rm -v %s' % item)
        print result.std_out
        print result.std_err
```

so far

Comment: Why don't you use `os.remove()`?

Comment: I want to work with envoy, but this is the next what i'll use then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
import envoy
import os

# Check for an empty folder. 
if len(os.listdir(csv_save_path)) != 0:
    for item in os.listdir(csv_save_path):
        result = envoy.run('rm -v %s' % item)
        print "Output: %s" % result.std_out
        print "Error: %s" % result.std_err
```

Comment: This won't work as expected if the string `item` contains spaces, tabs, newlines, single quotes, double quotes, and possibly other special characters.

The correct answer is: `envoy.run([['rm', '-v', '--', item]])`

Answer (score 4):

The second parameter of `envoy.run` is a  timeout. You want:

```
# The check for the empty folder is superfluous
for item in os.listdir(csv_save_path):
    filepath = os.path.join(csv_save_path, item)
    result = envoy.run(['rm', '-v', '--', filepath])
    print (result.std_out)
    print (result.std_err)
```

By the way, why are you using the command-line `rm` instead of Python's [`os.unlink`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.unlink)?

Comment: @Akendo The error message you get is correct; the file does not exist in the local directory. Updated the answer with a solution that uses [`os.path.join`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.join).

Comment: I did both, also i change into the folder. No use! All failed so far.

Comment: If you change into the folder, you'd have to call `os.listdir('.')` instead. Can you post the updated code? I overlooked that the error comes from Python - that means your code probably doesn't match the one in this answer. I'm assuming it looks something like: `envoy.run(['rm -v', filepath])`, which is wrong, since in the list notation, elements aren't split before given to `execve`.

Comment: For some reason there's a bug with envoy. The workaround is to pass a list within a list, like this: `envoy.run([['rm', '-v', '--', filepath]])`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [shlex.split](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shlex.html#shlex.split) to help you form the list to supply to envoy.run() instead of crafting/coding the list by hand.

E.g.

```
>>> from shlex import split
>>> split("rm -v -- filename")
['rm', '-v', '--', 'filename']
```

In your case, the code would look like this:

```
from shlex import split
# ......
result = envoy.run(split('rm -v %s' % (item)))
```